# How to enter a default value to custom meta fields in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I try to create a small plugin using a WordPress plugin named "Easy Theme Options" plugin.

For example, I tried to add an option:

```
$eto_custom_meta_fields = array(
array(
        'label' => 'Menu box shadow color',
        'desc'  => 'Menu box shadow color (Default: #ffffff)',
        'id'    => $prefix.'shadow',
        'type'  => 'colorpicker'
    ),
...
```

I'd like to add a default value. I tried to add the following line:

```
'default'   => 'fffff',
```

But it did not work. How can enter a default value to a custom meta field?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Please, add the [link to the plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-theme-options) next time... Checked its code, unfortunately, it doesn't have a "default value" feature.

Comment: @brasofilo. Sorry, I will do next time. And thanks for your answer. Are there any references which I can refer to for adding the default value feature?